# I need help on importing this specific table into my LaTeX report

Tags: tables

Can I get some help on what commands I can use in order to replicate this specific table.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want a table or would a matrix with the labels at the side be better, e.g., have a look here (http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) at p.17/18

Answer (score 1):

You can try my aproach.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc||c}
        \diagbox{Row}{Col} & 1 & $\cdots$ & j & $\cdots$ & 100 & 101 \\
        \hline
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        1 & $\chi_1(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_{101})$ \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        i & $\chi_i(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_{101})$ \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        215 & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_{101})$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would suggest to use as less as possible vertical lines.

**EDIT**

For other `\documentclass`, you can define a `table` environment and specify the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox} %for the (Row/Col) stuff

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc||c}
            \diagbox{Row}{Col} & 1 & $\cdots$ & j & $\cdots$ & 100 & 101 \\
            \hline
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            1 & $\chi_1(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_1(\lambda_{101})$ \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            i & $\chi_i(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_i(\lambda_{101})$ \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            215 & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_1)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_j)$ & $\cdots$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_{100})$ & $\chi_{215}(\lambda_{101})$ \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! do I put the \centering command after \begin{tabular}{c|ccccc||c} to centre the table?

Comment: @Malley For a document (`documentclass article`, ...) you can define a `table` environment, where you put the `\centering` command. I updated the answer!